# Item can not parent to slot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have and drop zone and i have a draggable object i can dran the object , also 
i can detect all the events with the help of debug.log.
I can also detect wen the object is drop but its seems to make the object parent
of the slot object is not work. 
I have no errors on my code:

I have included the screen shoot.
[image]

This is my code for the slot

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler {
public GameObject item 
{
    get {
        if (transform.childCount > 0) 
            {
                return transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
#region IDropHandler implementation
public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log ("ondrop");
    if (!item) 
    {
        DragHandler.itemBeginDragged.transform.SetParent (transform);

    }
}
#endregion


}
```

This is my code for item drag handdler

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, 
IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {
public static GameObject itemBeginDragged;
Vector3 startPosition;
Transform startParent;
#region IBeginDragHandler implementation

public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    itemBeginDragged = gameObject;
    startPosition = transform.position;
    startParent = transform.parent;
    //GetComponent<CanvasGroup> ().blocksRaycasts = false;
}
#endregion

#region IDragHandler implementation

public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    Debug.Log ("ondrag");
}
#endregion

#region IEndDragHandler implementation

public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    itemBeginDragged = null;
    //GetComponent<CanvasGroup> ().blocksRaycasts = true;
    if (transform.parent == startParent) 
    {
        transform.position = startPosition;
    }

}

#endregion
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `if (!item)` doesn't work very well? Try `if (item == null)`?

Comment: You say you don't have errors so I'll assume the above is just a typo since it should not compile. Please explain what you mean with "make the object parent of the slot is not work", tell us actual behaviour and desired behaviour; we cannot know what "doesn't work" mean in your case.

Comment: @FredrikSchön why should it not compile? [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) ([`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) inherits from it) provides an implicit convertion to `bool` which basically equals `!= null`

Comment: Oh, cool - TIL! Very javascript-esque, I like! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i finish but do it in a diferent way.

I solved the problem from the item not get parent on the slot by change a bit my code
This is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler {
public GameObject object1;
public GameObject object2;
public GameObject item 

{
    get {
        if (transform.childCount > 0) 
            {
                return transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
#region IDropHandler implementation
public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log ("ondrop");
    object1.transform.parent = object2.transform;

}
#endregion


}
```

Comment: And your variable names got worse. `object1`, really?

Comment: I don't understand why this would work, what's the difference between `this.gameObject`, `object1` & `item`? Is `Slot` on a canvas, and `object2` is not?

Comment: there is no diferefence that much about ,only a few diferent choices but i found a choice more easy to explain my problem also , i have found a solution for my problem with less work , of course i like to kwon how to deal on the must dificult way.